# Shell : Add input lines subset to prefix dig output

Tags: bash, shell, dig

At present,I get `NS(Name Server)` record for a list of domains in a loop fashion.

```
 #ns_check.sh
 for i in $(cat Input.txt);do dig +short NS $i;done
```

Input file has only domains.

```
#Input.txt
example.com
hello.com
blah.com
```

I get output as,

```
 #Out.txt
    ns4.p05.dynect.net.
    ns2.p05.dynect.net.
    ns1.p05.dynect.net.
    ns3.p05.dynect.net.
    ns-315.awsdns-39.com.
    ns-564.awsdns-06.net.
    ns-1162.awsdns-17.org.
    ns-1949.awsdns-51.co.uk.
    a3.verisigndns.com.
    u1.verisigndns.com.
    a2.verisigndns.com.
    a1.verisigndns.com.
    u2.verisigndns.com.
    u3.verisigndns.com.
```

Now, I would like to have my Input.txt as

```
  #Input.txt
    1,example.com
    2,hello.com
    3,blah.com
```

Output has to be like,

```
#Out.txt
        1,ns4.p05.dynect.net.
        1,ns2.p05.dynect.net.
        1,ns1.p05.dynect.net.
        1,ns3.p05.dynect.net.
        2,ns-315.awsdns-39.com.
        2,ns-564.awsdns-06.net.
        2,ns-1162.awsdns-17.org.
        2,ns-1949.awsdns-51.co.uk.
        3,a3.verisigndns.com.
        3,u1.verisigndns.com.
        3,a2.verisigndns.com.
        3,a1.verisigndns.com.
        3,u2.verisigndns.com.
        3,u3.verisigndns.com.
```

How to add the Input `ID` to the output of each and every NS record of domain obtained ? New to shell scripting,Any suggestions on how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `while` loop:

```
while IFS=, read -r n h; do
    printf "$n,%s\n" $(dig +short NS "$h")
done < input.txt
```

- `IFS=, read -r n h` will read each comma delimited line into 2 variables `n` (number) and `h` (host).
- `printf "$n,%s\n" $(dig +short NS "$h")` will replace each line start with `$n,` in the `dig` command's output.

Comment: Thank you @anubhava fixed the issue.